# Change Chart.js Query with Dropdown

Tags: django, chart.js

I have my chart.js chart loading fine using django rest framework. 
I want to preset different queries and have the chart change with a drop down, but not too sure where to start on this one, i have been able to piece together the current code from reading different articles online, but I am  no expert

currently my restframework pages produces this data. All good when i want to show all queries.

```
{
"lables": [
    "2017-09-06",
    "2017-09-24",
    "2018-07-06",
    "2018-07-10",
    "2018-08-13",
    "2018-08-16",
    "2018-09-06"
],
"default": [
    526,
    200,
    666,
    543,
    345,
    422,
    111
],
"lables_2017": [
    "2017-09-06",
    "2017-09-24"
],
"data_2017": [
    526,
    200
]
}
```

Here is a cutdown version of my code:

View.py

```
class ListComputers(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        lables = [computer.date for computer in Computer.objects.all().order_by('date')]
        default_items = [computer.computer_count for computer in Computer.objects.all().order_by('date')]
        lables_2017 = [computer.date for computer in Computer.objects.filter(date__year=2017)]
        data_2017 = [computer.computer_count for computer in Computer.objects.filter(date__year=2017)]
        data = {
            "lables": lables,
            "default": default_items,
            "lables_2017": lables_2017,
            "data_2017": data_2017,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

Myhtml.html

```
<div class="card-body" id="card_body">
          <select class="text_select" id="chart-select" onchange="myFunction()" name="chart-select">
            <option value="All">All Time</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
          </select>
          <canvas id="ComputerChart" width="100%" height="30"></canvas>
        </div>

<script>
var endpoint = 'api/chart/data'
var defaultData = []
var lables = []
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: endpoint,
  success: function(data){
    lables = data.lables
    defaultData = data.default
    setAPIChat()
    //console.log(data)
  },
  error: function(error_data){
    console.log("error")
    console.log(error_data)
  }
})

function setAPIChat(){
var ctx = document.getElementById("ComputerChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: lables,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Computer Count',
            data: defaultData,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
}
</script>
```

So first query works fine, but not too sure how to change the query now.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using for your frontend? jQuery, Angular, React?

Comment: apologies for not saying @Lewis, using jquery